# How to convert python tuple into a two dimentional table?

Tags: python

a flat (one dimension) tuple on input:

```
data = ('a','b','c'.....'z');
```

output: table (two dimensions) that has n (say 9) columns

```
table = ?what code here?
```

so

```
print table
 ( ('a','b','c'...), ('k','l','m','n'...), ....)
```

which is the shortest way to do so?

Comment: related: [What is the most "pythonic" way to iterate over a list in chunks?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/434287/)

Answer (score 7):

Here's the short version if you find the rest of this too wordy:

```
n = 9
table = zip(*[iter(data)]*n)
```

Let's say you start with a list:

```
>>> data = range(1,101)
>>> data
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34,
35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66,
67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82,
83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98,
99, 100]
```

Create an iterator for your list:

```
>>> data_iter = iter(data)
```

Now use the `zip` function to split up the list.  Pay attention, this is the
fun part!

```
>>> table = zip(*[data_iter]*9)
>>> pprint.pprint(table)
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
 (10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18),
 (19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27),
 (28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36),
 (37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45),
 (46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54),
 (55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63),
 (64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72),
 (73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81),
 (82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90),
 (91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99)]
```

The expression `[data_iter]*9' results in the following list:

```
[ data_iter, data_iter, data_iter, data_iter, data_iter, 
data_iter, data_iter, data_iter, data_iter ]
```

The expresion `*[data_iter]*9` turns this into nine arguments to the `zip`
function.  This `zip` function builds a list of tuples:

> Return a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the i-th element
>      from each of the argument sequences.  The returned list is truncated
>      in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence.

Because we're using an iterator, every time `zip` function looks for a new value it gets the next value in the sequence.  Contrast this with the behavior if we had simply used a list the same way:

```
>>> table = zip(*[data]*9)
>>> pprint.pprint(table)
[(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
 (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
 (3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
 ...
 (99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99),
 (100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100)]
```

**UPDATE**: My colleague points out that if you have NumPy available, you can
do this:

```
>>> data = numpy.array(range(1,101))
>>> data.reshape([10,10])
array([[  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10],
   [ 11,  12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  20],
   [ 21,  22,  23,  24,  25,  26,  27,  28,  29,  30],
   [ 31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,  39,  40],
   [ 41,  42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47,  48,  49,  50],
   [ 51,  52,  53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58,  59,  60],
   [ 61,  62,  63,  64,  65,  66,  67,  68,  69,  70],
   [ 71,  72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,  78,  79,  80],
   [ 81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89,  90],
   [ 91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99, 100]])
```

Comment: That seems almost too clever.

Comment: This is actually the canonical way of accomplishing this task.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
table = tuple(data[n:n+9] for n in xrange(0,len(data),9))
```

Returns a tuple made from stepping through `data` 9 items at a time.
If you want to change the number of columns, just change both nines in the generator

Comment: When I use timeit to time your solution and larsks solution, yours seems to be faster. 1,000,000 calls yields a total of 4.43 for yours and 5.02 for his (I could also be doing something wrong).

Comment: It's possible that list comprehensions are faster than function calls.  I just think iterators are nifty.

Comment: Well, I just used `cProfile` to time them. @larsks is actually twice as fast, it seems. Also, only four function calls versus my 100004 (for a 90000 item tuple).

Comment: I only did a couple tries on each, so no average times, but from how many I did do it looks pretty consistent: about 75% - 100% for @larsks method. Pity, I thought mine was pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised this isn't in `itertools`, but it doesn't seem to be. Here's my approach:

```
def segment_list(lst, step):
    """
    Segment lst into a list of step-length lists
    """
    segments = []
    while True:
        if len(lst) <= step:
            output.append(lst)
            break
        output.append(lst[0:step])
        lst = lst[step+1:]
    return segments
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> n = 3
>>> data = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
...        'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
...        'm', 'n')

>>> table = []    

>>> for i in xrange( 0, divmod( len(data), n)[0] + 1):
...     table.append( data[i*n:i*n+n] )

>>> print tuple( table )
(('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('g', 'h', 'i'), ('j', 'k', 'l'), ('m', 'n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Daenth,

The zip method described by larsks (above) *is* described in the itertools module documentation - search for "grouper" among the recipes:

- http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes